# Converting UTC time to seconds

Tags: matlab

I have a UTC Timestamp on my acquired data in the format :

```
hh:mm:ss.SS
```

This data is taken at 20 ms and I need it to convert to the duration in seconds and make a time series of it taking into account the start time and end time (even milliseconds took into account)
I am currently using :

```
Dp = duration(hh,mm:mm,ss:ss);
tp= (minutes(D))*60;
```

Guidance required to make it into a time series which is generic in the way that milliseconds are taken into account as well. I am using MATLAB R2020a as a tool.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out from MATLAB Forum the answer and would like to share my answer here for the greater good.

The table A comprises of my time data in UTC in the 'hh:mm:ss.SS' format and I have used following script to make the time data into time series in seconds:

```
Dpt = table2array(A);
formatSpec = 'hh:mm:ss.SS';
dp = duration(Dpt, 'InputFormat', formatSpec, 'Format', formatSpec);
Tp = hours(dp)*3600+(minutes(dp))*60 +seconds(dp);
```